# Plural of implementer

Tags: british-english

Just a quick question, is implementers the plural of the word implementer?

My computer spellcheck complains about it, however https://www.thefreedictionary.com/implementers and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/implementer#English seem to think it is a proper word.

Can anyone shed any light on what the correct plural of the word implementer is?

Comment: Spell checkers are only intended to *suggest* that you examine a word to see if it's spelled correctly.  Their vocabularies are generally quite limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Implementer* = someone whose job is to put a plan or system into action
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/implementer)

Hence the simple plural *implemeters*. I see no reasonable alternative, despite the oddities of dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you for this :)